# passing data to an ajax request jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

When i am trying to send data through ajax, its not passing data

```
$('#savenew').click(function () {
  var user = <?php echo $user?>;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "actions/sub.php",
    data: user,
    success: function () {
      $('#savenew').html('<span>Unsubscribe</span>');
      $(this).removeAttr('id');
      $(this).attr('id', 'clean');
    }
  });
});
```

My PHP code on receiving end,

```
if ($_POST['user']) {
 $user = $_POST['user'];
}
```

Am i doing something wrong ? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
data: user,
```

should be

```
data: {user: user},
```

Because you're looking for a POST variable called "user" and using its value. jQuery will accept an object literal and serialize it into POST data using the property names as keys and the property values as values. The nice thing about using an object (literal or otherwise) is that then jQuery handles doing the encoding of the values for you. You *can* use a string (`data: "user=" + user`), but then you have to worry about doing the `encodeURIComponent` part yourself for string parameters (no need for this numeric one).

You can also just do it all in one, with no `user` variable on the client side:

```
$('#savenew').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "actions/sub.php",
        data: {user: <?php echo $user?>},
        success: function(){
            $('#savenew').html('<span>Unsubscribe</span>');
            $(this).removeAttr('id');
            $(this).attr('id', 'clean');
        }
    });
});
```

...although having the `user` variable client-side is harmless, and of course if you want to use it in more than one place...

Comment: @getaway: Ah, good; I've removed the string part of the answer.

Comment: thanks it works, can i ask you, if i wanted to make this ajax request secure, what shall i avoid or do :) thanks +1 from me

Comment: @getaway: No worries. The question of how to make the request secure is different enough from this question that I'd ask it separately. (Also, I think it's probably already been answered on SO, so search around a bit first. FWIW, I find SO's own search feature to be pretty unreliable, so instead I use Google with "site:stackoverflow.com".)

Comment: cheers! thanks i will take that into mind, i will accept your answer when it lets me :))